# Django Managers

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

I have the following models code :

```
from django.db import models
from categories.models import Category

class MusicManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(MusicManager, self).get_query_set().filter(category='Music')
    def count_music(self):
        return self.all().count()

class SportManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(MusicManager, self).get_query_set().filter(category='Sport')        

class Event(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    objects = models.Manager()
    music = MusicManager()
    sport = SportManager()
```

Now by registering MusicManager() and SportManager() I am able to call Event.music.all() and Event.sport.all() queries. But how can I create Event.music.count() ? Should I call self.all() in count_music() function of MusicManager to query only on elements with 'Music' category or do I still need to filter through them in search for category first ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of a manager as a 'starting point' for a query - you can continue to chain filters just as if you'd started out with the default manager.

For example, `Event.objects.filter(category='Music').filter(title='Beatles Concert')` is functionally equivalent to `Event.music.filter(title='Beatles Concert')`

So, as Daniel says, you don't really need to do anything special, just choose one of your custom managers instead of `objects` and go from there.

Comment: It is the start point and end point. To get anything 'in between' you will want something like this snippet: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/734/ Be sure to check out the comments...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything (and your `count_music` method is unnecessary). The `count()` method will use the existing query as defined by `get_query_set`.

Comment: cont() is just an example. Let's say filter_city('City') or anything else. I'm just wondering if in this custom manager if i want to create function for even more specific query, can I use .all() or nothing at all or do I need to filter category once again ?